# Is it acceptable to present the same project at two conferences and list them separately on my CV?

Tags: conference, ethics, cv, presentation

Is it acceptable to present the same project at two conferences and list them separately on your CV?

The two conferences are for different audiences (one is for educators and faculty members and the other is for a more interdisciplinary population). This being the case, the project itself will not change. However, the analysis of the data and the emphasis on the implications of it are drastically different for the two conferences.

I have seen elsewhere online that the recommended course of action would be to simply cite the more well-known conference and only that one. However, since the analyses of data are different for the two conferences, would it be deemed acceptable to list them as separate entries on my CV?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I give the same talk in multiple venues*, I list the title of the presentation once, then underneath all the places I've presented it. For example:

> **On the use of nanofibers in basket weaving**
>
> 20th Annual Meeting of the Society for Basket Weavers (July 2016), Department of Basket Weaving Seminar at East South University (August 2016), Workshop on Innovative Use of Nanofibers (October 2016)

If it's a *different* presentation (e.g. different title), even if part of the same project, I'd list separate entries.

---

* Only at venues which accept work that has already been presented, of course.

Comment: It will most likely be under a different title because while the data will be pulled from the same project, the analysis itself will be entirely different for each audience! Thank you, this cleared it up nicely!

Answer (score 0):

They are two different presentations at all effects. So whether you write it twice on your CV or not, should only depend on how "heavy" is your curriculum. I would use two entries if I had only those two conference talks, or just a bit more, and one single entry if I have >10 conference talks under my belt. To give you an idea, once you have given over 15/20 different talks about different projects at different venues, you would most likely keep on your CV only the most relevant ones.

Comment: Ah I see! I only have about 8 conference talks so far so I will note of your suggestion! Thank you!

Comment: Glad to help. Please take my numbers with a grain of salt though. At the end, what you want to show is that you have a good balance in all aspects of academic achievement. That is the only reason to keep the conference talks to a reasonable size, that is to say, not to overwhelm your CV with a single type of achevement.